# Scanning Jaalee Ibeacon using Evothings Cordova Plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, ibeacon-android, estimote

I am working on a Hybrid Mobile App. I have a requirement that i have to scan an iBeacon Id. For that purpose, i bought a Jaalee iBeacon.

Now I searched here and there on internet and found [Evothings Ibeacon Examples](https://github.com/evothings/evothings-examples) which has an iBeacon Scan Example. I tried with this, I entered my jaalee ibeacon UUID in the regions array. But this didnt work at all. My iBeacon did not appear in the result as i executed the code.

I also added [petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon), but still its not showing my ibeacon.

Does it work for Estimote Beacons only and not for Jaalee Beacons.

Any idea ? or Any sort of help /clue is much appreciated.

Comment: You might also try the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), which is known to work with Jaalee beacons.  If you elect to go this route, you must add a BeaconParser for the iBeacon format.  You can search Google to find out how to do that.

Comment: thanks @davidgyoung .. will check this out and let you know..

Comment: Take a look at [cordova-plugin-boni](https://github.com/BONI-hub/cordova-plugin-boni). It is great for development of hybrid mobile apps that interact with iBeacons because it is not only detecting (ranging) the iBeacons but also a platform that enables you to map content to the iBeacon. I will happy if you share your experience.